# How do I run Console.Write() on every new line?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console

How would I go about running `Console.Write()` on every new line?

Note that I do not want to use `Console.WriteLine()` because I still want to take input from that line.

Comment: Do you mean `Console.ReadLine()`?

Comment: The question is really not clear at all. `Console.Write();` requires an argument to be passed to it (typically a `string`), and then it writes that string to the console window. What exactly are you trying to do? `prompt` is used to get user input. Perhaps you're looking for something like: `Console.Write("Enter your name: "); string name = Console.ReadLine();`? Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Console.Write("\nInput your text here:");`

\n in strings starts prints to a new line.

Comment: If OP wants to recreate `prompt` then it is a read, not a write.